# Why the last 'printf' function didn't execute?

Tags: c, return

I'm new to C, I'm confused why the last 'printf' function didn't execute. printf("%d:%.2d %c.m., arriving at %d:%.2d %c.m.\n")

The outcome is 'Closest departure time is 9:45 p.m., arriving at 11:58 p.m.' Why the outcome is not 'Closest departure time is 9:45 p.m., arriving at 11:58 p.m.
Closest departure time is 9:45 p.m., arriving at 11:58 p.m.'

Now I realize it because of 'return 0' in the loop, but I don't know why.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
int i,
    user_time,
    hour,
    d_hour,
    d_minute,
    a_hour,
    a_minute,
    minute,
    dep[8] = {480, 583, 679, 767, 840, 945, 1140, 1305},
    arr[8] = {616, 712, 811, 900, 968, 1075, 1280, 1438};

printf("Enter a 24-hour time: ");
scanf("%d :%d", &hour, &minute);
user_time = hour * 60 + minute;

printf("Closest departure time is ");

for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    if (user_time <= dep[i] + 
        (dep[i + 1] - dep[i]) / 2) {

        d_hour = dep[i] / 60 > 12 ? dep[i] / 60 - 12 : dep[i] / 60;
        d_minute = dep[i] % 60;
        a_hour = arr[i] / 60 > 12 ? arr[i] / 60 - 12 : arr[i] / 60;
        a_minute = arr[i] % 60;

        printf("%d:%.2d %c.m., arriving at %d:%.2d %c.m.\n", 
               d_hour, d_minute, dep[i] / 60 > 11 ? 'p' : 'a',
               a_hour, a_minute, arr[i] / 60 > 11 ? 'p' : 'a');
        return 0;
    }
}

d_hour = dep[7] / 60 > 12 ? dep[7] / 60 - 12 : dep[7] / 60;
d_minute = dep[7] % 60;
a_hour = arr[7] / 60 > 12 ? arr[7] / 60 - 12 : arr[7] / 60;
a_minute = arr[7] % 60;

printf("%d:%.2d %c.m., arriving at %d:%.2d %c.m.\n",
       d_hour, d_minute, dep[7] / 60 > 11 ? 'p' : 'a',
       a_hour, a_minute, arr[7] / 60 > 11 ? 'p' : 'a');
```

Comment: Probably because you `return` inside the loop? Perhaps you should only `break` out of the loop instead?

Comment: @Some programmer dude Thank you. It is an answer to a book, and I don't understand why it works. When there is 'return 0' in the loop, what the effect of it?

Comment: You want to print the last entry from the timetable if none of earlier enties fit the user's input. When you find an appropriate departure, say at 8 in the loop, then you don't need to print the last entry, so you can skip the rest of the function simply by returning from it.

Comment: Clarification: I meant 8 a.m. in the comment above, not the 8-th entry in the array.

Comment: @CiaPan Thank you very much, and I know what you mean. I understand the program now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function exits from inside the `for` loop due to the `return 0;`, hence the last `printf` is never executed.

**Added**

If you do not know why the internal `return` skips the last print, you lack a basic knowledge about the language you use.

In C language, the `return` statement causes immediate termination of the function in which it is executed. In other words, it jumps to the closing brace with a specified return value, i.e. a result of the function.

If you want to terminate the loop but not exit the function, use `break` instead of `return`. Be aware though, that `break` breakes the 'closest' loop only—if you use it in a nested loop, like this:

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    // do some stuff with i

    for (j=0; j<4; j++)
    {
        // do some stuff with j

        if (some_condition)
            break;              // <----- break here

        // do more stuff about j
    }

    // do more stuff about i
}
// the rest of the program
```

then the `break` inside the inner loop will bring the execution just past that loop's end, to the `do more stuff about i` point, not to `the rest of the program`.

**Added**

If you do understand *how the return works* but not *why it was used there*, then you lack a basic knowledge of your program's logic.

You seek a departure time that fits the user's needs, according to the input. For this you need to use each departure time *and* the next departure time. However, there is no *next* departure after the last one in the timetable, so you scan the table till one-but-last item.

Then you want to print the last entry from the timetable if none of earlier entries fits the user's input. If you find an appropriate departure in the loop, say at `i==3`, then you print it and you needn't print the last entry. Then you can skip the rest of the function simply by returning from it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is another 'return 0' for the main function after the last printf. If dep[0] to dep[6] can not meet the condition, the program would execute the part after 'return 0'. Now I realize it because return 0, but I don't know why.

Comment: @Charles Please see the expanded answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
**d_hour** = dep[7] / 60 > 12 ? dep[7] / 60 - 12 : **dep[7] / 60**;
printf("**%d**:%.2d %c.m., arriving at %d:%.2d %c.m.\n",
d_hour, d_minute, dep[7] / 60 > 11 ? 'p' : 'a',
_hour, a_minute, arr[7] / 60 > 11 ? 'p' : 'a');
```

Your d_hour will have the result of dep[7] / 60 which results to float datatype.
but i can able to see  that printf is expecting %d which is integer data type.
pls use data conversion or use '%f' to print the data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is still 'int' type, because of C's feature.

Comment: Nope, Both expressions, `dep[7]` and `60` are of type `int`, so the result of division `dep[7] / 60` is `int`, too.